# filter search table html

Tags: php, html

i was tring to implement the search filter on this code but i still dont know how to figure it out any help would be appreciated. i was trying to apply the search filter into my database to display after i have type the word. this is my reference link from w3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtGqU.png)
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

```
<script>




 function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("SearchList");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
  </script> 

<!-- MODAL SEARCH LIST -->
<div class="modal fade" id="SearchList" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> 
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            &times;
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">
            <img src="./includes/themes/img/tirematicslogo.png" width="150"  alt="SmartAdmin">
          </h4>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body no-padding">
        <fieldset>
          <section>
            <div class="row">
              <label class="label col col-3">Serial Number:<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              <div class="col col-9">
                <label class="input">
                <i class="icon-append fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>
                <input type="text" id="SearchList" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
                <ul id="myUL">
                  <?php
                      $qryBrand = tep_query( "SELECT * FROM nano_tire WHERE fleet_id='0' AND tire_status='1' AND tire_data= 'In Stock'" );
                   while ( $infoRow = tep_fetch_object( $qryBrand ) ) {
                        echo <li>$infoRow->tire_id</li>;  
                            echo"<br>";
                      }
                      ?>
                </ul>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <div id="SearchResult"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <footer>
          <input type="hidden" value="" id="Searchtire" name="Searchtire">
          <input type="hidden" value="" id="Searchaxle" name="Searchaxle">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?=$_POST['id']?>" id="Searchfleetid" name="Searchfleetid">
          <input type="hidden" value="" id="Searchtirenum" name="Searchtirenum">
          <button type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openSearch()">Done</button>
          <button type="" class="btn btn-default" onclick="cancelsearchtire()">Cancel</button>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have <a> tag as a child of <li> ? because in your code you are just using <li>$infoRow->tire_id</li>. It would be great if you paste the HTML code by copying the code from the View Page Source option.

Comment: i just put in the tag like you said but the code still have the problem because i want to display the query

Comment: Maybe I was not clear with the requirements. Actually, you posted the PHP code what I wanted to say is paste the HTML code instead (output of this page). You can get it by right click on the browser and selecting the View Page Source option.